# How to create the SqlQuerySpec in Java in order to retrieve a list of documents with given ids (where-in clause)

Tags: java, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi, where-in, azure-java-sdk

I am working on Azure Cosmos DB with SQL Api. I am using Azure SDK from:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
    <artifactId>azure-documentdb</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.7</version>
</dependency>
```

I have a list of **ids**, and I would like to find all documents with **ids** from my list. In order to achieve that I an using Azure SDK SqlQuerySpec, where i defined a "WHERE IN" query as follows:

```
List<String> ids = Lists.newArrayList("1");
SqlQuerySpec spec = new SqlQuerySpec(
    "SELECT * FROM MyLog c WHERE c.id IN (@ids)", 
    new SqlParameterCollection(new SqlParameter("@ids", ids)));
FeedResponse<Document> documentFeedResponse = documentClient.queryDocuments(collectionLink, spec, queryOptions);
List<Document> documents = documentFeedResponse.getQueryIterable().toList();
```

But unfortunately the "documents" list is empty, although in my database I have a document with id=1. Just to double check I have tried to run the query in portal:

> SELECT * FROM c where c.id IN ("1")

it returns the data correctly. So I am not sure what I am doing wrong. 
Anyone have already created the SqlQuerySpec in order to retrieve a list of documents with given ids?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, `IN` is used like `where c.id IN ("1")`, the param is not array.

You could use `Array_Contains` to implement your need:

```
List<String> ids = new ArrayList<String>();
ids.add("1");
ids.add("2");
SqlQuerySpec spec = new SqlQuerySpec(
           "SELECT * FROM c WHERE array_contains(@ids, c.id )",
           new SqlParameterCollection(new SqlParameter("@ids", ids)));
FeedResponse<Document> documentFeedResponse = documentClient.queryDocuments(collectionLink, spec, feedOptions);
            List<Document> documents = documentFeedResponse.getQueryIterable().toList();
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: this works perfectly. On the top of that question, If I had a list of type Long? List<Long> ids = ... then is there a way to retrieve the data without  transforming longs into strings?

Comment: @fascynacja no matter it is long or string,it should be corresponding.

Comment: it did not work for me. Could you try to run your example but instead List<String> use List<Long> ?

Comment: @fascynacja The id is cosmos db should be string, i think. If you want to use Long in code,i think you need to convert it in the sql because they are dismatch.

Comment: @fascynacja If you do not want to use string, have to use long.Then you could leave the id, create id column by yourself. Such as userId,deviceId....

Comment: for now I transformed List<Long> into List<String>. I will think about the solutions you mentioned, thank you.

Comment: @fascynacja You're welcome! Any concern,pls let me know.

Comment: error comes as this constructor is not defined. Can you help me with the code, including maven dependencies.